# Can apache's ProxyRemote be used to proxy HTTPS requests to mongrel for processing?

Tags: ruby, apache, mongrel

So I have a custom proxy that is written in ruby using mongrel to handle some fairly complex caching logic.  This works great for both http and ftp requests, however since mongrel is not designed to handle https requests, I wish to front the whole thing with apache and make use of the ProxyRemote command to pass through to mongrel for https requests.

This sort of thing is easily accomplished to mirror certain site directory structures via the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse commands in apache, but I don't see a way to do this using ProxyRemote.

The problem is that mongrel does not handle CONNECT requests which are made to establish a secure request.  So while I am able to handle https requests within the proxy itself, actually using the proxy with an https request directly is not supported.

It seems that the simplest solution would be to have apache handle the https request and then simply pass the http request itself (minus the CONNECT) to mongrel and have it handle it appropriately and return it to apache and then to the client.

So my question is, Is there a way to make ProxyRemote work the same way that ProxyPass does with HTTP requests (i.e. pass an unencrypted request to mongrel)?

Answer (score 1):

Just use ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse, the connection between your reverse proxy (apache) and your mongrel will see normal plain http :), no magic necessary (especially not CONNECT, afaik thats only possbile for forward proxies, but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 0):

Hum, have you tried to do so ?

I've been using apache to do the https and just pass the requests with the old default .htaccess mod_rewrite rules.